# Mapping data recieved from Angular in .net using mediatR

Tags: .net, api, mapping, domain-driven-design, mediatr

I'm sending data from my angular App in FormData
this is the print of the data sent
Key: tePartNumber, Value: test
Key: customerPN, Value: test
Key: projectNumber, Value: test
Key: oem, Value: 994f433e-f36b-1410-9006-00a33fe338d1
Key: harnessMaker, Value: e14f433e-f36b-1410-9006-00a33fe338d1
Key: numberOfConnectors, Value: 2
Key: cdPath, Value: [object File]
Key: pdPath, Value: [object File]
Key: excelFilePath, Value: null
Key: imagePath, Value: [object File]
Key: componentsData, Value: {"componentId":"e94f433e-f36b-1410-9006-00a33fe338d1","side":"left"}
Key: componentsData, Value: {"componentId":"e94f433e-f36b-1410-9006-00a33fe338d1","side":"right"}
Key: cablesData, Value: {"componentId":"dd4f433e-f36b-1410-9006-00a33fe338d1"}
in my .net part im using MediatR to recieve the data and map it

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<RequestResponseMessage>> SaveDrawingData([FromForm] SaveDrawingDataCommand command)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Compoentdata :"+ command.componentsData.Count);
                var response = await Mediator.Send(command);
                return Ok(response);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while saving the drawing data.");
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

this calls should map the data recieved to an instance of SaveDrawingDataCommand

```
     public class SaveDrawingDataCommand : IRequest<SaveDrawingDataResponse>
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set;}
        public string? tePartNumber { get; set; }
        public string? customerPN { get; set; }
        public string? projectNumber { get; set; }
        public string? oem { get; set; }
        public string? harnessMaker { get; set; }
        public int numberOfConnectors { get; set; }
        public List<ComponentsDataDto>? componentsData { get; set; }
        public List<CablesDataDto>? cablesData { get; set; }
        public IFormFile? cdPath { get; set; }
        public IFormFile? pdPath { get; set; }
        public IFormFile? excelFilePath { get; set; }
        public IFormFile? imagePath { get; set; }

    }
```

and SaveDrawingDataCommand implement IRequest
this automatically calls  SaveDrawingDataCommandHandler

```
 public async Task<SaveDrawingDataResponse> Handle(SaveDrawingDataCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var command = _mapper.Map<SaveDrawingDataCommand>(request);

        var drawingData = new Backend.Domain.Entities.DrawingData
        {

            tePartNumber = request.tePartNumber,
            customerPN = request.customerPN,
            projectNumber = request.projectNumber,
            oem =Guid.Parse( request.oem),
            harnessMaker = Guid.Parse(request.harnessMaker),
            numberOfConnectors = request.numberOfConnectors, 

        };

        //  Add the files paths to DrawingData
        drawingData.cdPath = await SaveFile(request.cdPath, drawingData.tePartNumber + "CD.pdf", baseUrl);
        drawingData.pdPath = await SaveFile(request.pdPath, drawingData.tePartNumber + "PD.pdf", baseUrl);
        drawingData.excelFilePath = await SaveFile(request.excelFilePath, drawingData.tePartNumber + "SmartAssembly.xlsm", baseUrl);
        drawingData.imagePath = await SaveFile(request.imagePath, drawingData.tePartNumber +".jpeg", baseUrl);
        
        var drawings = await _drawingDataRepository.Create(drawingData, cancellationToken);


       foreach (ComponentsData componentDto in request.componentsData)
        {
             Console.WriteLine($"ComponentId: {componentDto.componentId}, Side: {componentDto.side}");
            var componentsData = new ComponentsData
            {
                componentId = componentDto.componentId,
                side = componentDto.side,   

            };
           
             await _componentWithSideRepository.Create(componentsData, cancellationToken);
            drawingData.componentsData.Add(componentsData);
        }

        // Ajouter les câbles
        foreach (CablesData cableDto in request.cablesData)
        { Console.WriteLine($"CablesId: {cableDto.cablesId}, Length: {cableDto.length}");
            var cablesData = new CablesData
            {
                cablesId = cableDto.cablesId,
                length = cableDto.length,

            };

            await _cablesDataRepository.Create(cablesData, cancellationToken);
            drawingData.cablesData.Add(cablesData);
        }
    
        var response = new SaveDrawingDataResponse
        {
            Message = "Drawing data saved successfully",
            Succeed = true,
            // You can set any other properties in the response as needed
        };

        return response;
    }
```

The problem is that i have access to all the data received expect componentsData, and cablesData when i try to console log them i all time have empty items, and when i try to print the value of componentsdata in the controller calling the handl méthode i got also empty iteam

```
 Console.WriteLine("Compoentdata :"+ command.componentsData.Count);
```

`Compoentdata :0`

it's been more thatn 10 day i'm trying to fix that problem, but im lost ...  can someone help me plz !!

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be related to the way your are sending data from angular.
componentsData and cablesData are not being handled correctly as lists in your input, hence the mapping is not working for these 2 properties. Here's an example of the Json that should be sent to your API:

```
     {
  "Id": "c719b1fd",
  "tePartNumber": "ABC123",
  "customerPN": "XYZ456",
  "projectNumber": "P123",
  "oem": "Example OEM",
  "harnessMaker": "Harness Maker Inc.",
  "numberOfConnectors": 5,
  "componentsData": [
    {
      "componentId": "1",
      "side": "left"
    },
    {
      "componentId": "2",
      "side": "right"
    }
  ],
  "cablesData": [
    {
      "componentId": "3",
      "side": "right"
    },
    {
      "componentId": "4",
      "side": "right"
    }
  ],
  "cdPath": null,
  "pdPath": null,
  "excelFilePath": null,
  "imagePath": null
}
```